# JSP files not deployed to Pivotal Web Services when using Spring Boot project

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I have a simple Spring Boot webmvc application with a JSP page working locally, but when I deploy onto Pivotal Web Services (hosted by Pivotal.io), I get an error when viewing the JSP page.  The app is packaged as WAR:

```
2015-02-11 12:22:30.381 ERROR 31 --- [io-61338-exec-4] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Looking closely at the files on the remote system, it seems my JSP files are not getting deployed.  They get deleted.  They are in the WAR before I deploy.

I have tried deploying from STS 3.6.3 SR1 and from the command line using CF.

When I create a regular Spring MVC project (not using Spring Boot), everything seems to work both locally and on pivotal web services cloud.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a configuration setting I missed?  Please help.  Thanks.

Here is my Spring Boot project setup:

Code for HomeController.java:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage() {
       return "home";
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHWorldApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ServletInitializer:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SpringBootHWorldApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Application.Properties file:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

My jsp page located in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.somecompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootHWorldExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootHWorld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.SpringBootHWorldApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The files on the remote system.  Note the folder /WEB-INF/views is missing.  I tried moving the files to a different location but every time the files are missing even though it works locally.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz8p7su2ksboc2o/RemoteFiles.png

And finally the deployment log:

```
Checking application - SpringBootHWorld
Generating application archive
Creating application
Pushing application
Application successfully pushed
Starting and staging application
Got staging request for app with id 3e09036b-1575-42ac-9642-f667506f7c53
Updated app with guid 3e09036b-1575-42ac-9642-f667506f7c53 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
    -----> Downloaded app package (7.6M)
    -----> Java Buildpack Version: v2.6.1 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#2d92e70
    -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_31 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/lucid/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_31.tar.gz (1.8s)
           Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.2s)
    -----> Downloading Spring Auto Reconfiguration 1.7.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.7.0_RELEASE.jar (0.1s)
    -----> Downloading Tomcat Instance 8.0.18 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.18.tar.gz (0.4s)
           Expanding Tomcat to .java-buildpack/tomcat (0.1s)
    -----> Downloading Tomcat Lifecycle Support 2.4.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat-lifecycle-support/tomcat-lifecycle-support-2.4.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
    -----> Downloading Tomcat Logging Support 2.4.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat-logging-support/tomcat-logging-support-2.4.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)

    -----> Uploading droplet (54M)
    Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3e09036b-1575-42ac-9642-f667506f7c53
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-61338"]
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Initialization processed in 511 ms
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService           INFO    Starting service Catalina
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine            INFO    Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deploying web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    [CONTAINER] ing.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer INFO    Initializing ServletContext with Auto-reconfiguration ApplicationContextInitializers
    [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@68430648, demo.ServletInitializer@6459b75d]

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
    2015-02-11 12:22:27.338  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] pertySourceApplicationContextInitializer : Adding 'cloud' PropertySource to ApplicationContext
    2015-02-11 12:22:27.397  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
    2015-02-11 12:22:27.417  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on 18eod7e1vho with PID 31 (/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar started by vcap in /home/vcap/app)
    2015-02-11 12:22:27.453  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a2c932: startup date [Wed Feb 11 12:22:27 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    2015-02-11 12:22:27.997  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
    2015-02-11 12:22:28.192  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] urceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Auto-reconfiguring beans of type javax.sql.DataSource
    2015-02-11 12:22:28.198  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] urceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping auto-reconfiguration.
    2015-02-11 12:22:28.362  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2015-02-11 12:22:28.362  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 909 ms
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.170  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.172  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.172  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.172  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.413  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a2c932: startup date [Wed Feb 11 12:22:27 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.494  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String demo.HomeController.viewHomePage()
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.497  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.497  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.523  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.524  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.561  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.636  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    2015-02-11 12:22:29.646  INFO 31 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 3.053 seconds (JVM running for 5.418)
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deployment of web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 4,709 ms
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-61338"]
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool         INFO    Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Server startup in 4766 ms
    2015-02-11 12:22:30.055  INFO 31 --- [io-61338-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2015-02-11 12:22:30.056  INFO 31 --- [io-61338-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
    2015-02-11 12:22:30.072  INFO 31 --- [io-61338-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 16 ms
    SpringBootHWorld.cfapps.io - [11/02/2015:12:22:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Java/1.7.0_45" 10.10.2.122:36854 x_forwarded_for:"50.187.174.41" vcap_request_id:e3177b90-5b1b-4325-6268-3f23c3b85d34 response_time:0.099450479 app_id:3e09036b-1575-42ac-9642-f667506f7c53
    2015-02-11 12:22:30.116 ERROR 31 --- [io-61338-exec-2] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
    2015-02-11 12:22:30.381 ERROR 31 --- [io-61338-exec-4] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
    springboothworld.cfapps.io - [11/02/2015:12:22:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36" 10.10.2.122:36858 x_forwarded_for:"50.187.174.41" vcap_request_id:ce3100c1-c592-452f-7174-06c4c28bcc2e response_time:0.015669152 app_id:3e09036b-1575-42ac-9642-f667506f7c53
```

Comment: According to this post: http://webserver.docs.pivotal.io/doc/60/web-server/src/config.html ,and then set com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

Comment: I am using PWS in the cloud hosted by pivotal.  I don't think I can get into the machine and make any changes.  Any changes would have to be in my Spring Boot app.  What would I need to do there?

Comment: If you're going to be deploying to CF, I suggest using jar packaging instead of war. It's easier to run locally and less likely to have odd assembly issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial answer here was deleted by someone and so OP and I were interacting [elsewhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQk9-2eQKfQ&google_comment_id=z12ddxkaxlytwbnp304cifnghv3aw3pre5g). In summary, it is found that using STS for the deployment isn't working, and using the `cf` command line tool ([say, as described here](http://naturalprogrammer.com/2015/02/06/pivotal-cloud-foundry-spring-boot-web-applications/)) works instead. Thought to report it here so that it could be of use for someone who stumbles upon this post.

Comment: Using the command CF does seem to work without having to make any configuration changes as I noted in my other answer.  I have verified this now several times.  Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1):

After much troubleshooting, I believe I figured out my problem.  To get things working, I did the following:

1. Right mouse click on the project and choose properties.
2. Select Project Facets.
3. Uncheck Dynamic Web Module and exit from the dialog.
4. Go back to project facets
5. Check Dynamic Web Module and choose the link "Further configuration available..."
6. Type in the path in the Content directory as "src/main/webapp".
7. Exit out of the dialogs.

This did two things.

Firstly, this added the META-INF folder with a manifest file in my webapp directory.

Secondly, it updated the file org.eclipse.wst.common.component in the .settings folder.

Before the changes described above, the following line was present:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
```

Contents of org.eclipse.wst.common.component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="SpringBootHelloWorld-06">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="demo"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/SpringBootHelloWorld-06/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

I also experimented with just adding the META-INF folder manually with the manifest file but it did not work.  So I suspect, the change in this file may be the reason, although I don't know for sure.  Perhaps someone with deeper knowledge in this area can shed some light.

Comment: I had posted something which I think might have been very useful, but someone deleted it. However, I have reposted it as a comment at youtube, in case it would help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQk9-2eQKfQ